# When using "and" in Ruby, the earth is flat

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

As I have always been taught in logic, the `and` operator means both values must be true, for the entire statement to be true. If you have many statements chained with `and`, then any one of them being false should make the whole claim false. In Ruby, however, I ran into this scenario:

```
horizon_flat = true
one_up_and_down = true
magellan_fell = false
flat_earth_thesis = horizon_flat and one_up_and_down and magellan_fell

puts("Hey ruby, doesn't the horizon look flat?")
puts(horizon_flat) # true

puts("Isn't there only one up and one down?")
puts(one_up_and_down) # true

puts("Did Magellan fall off the earth?")
puts(magellan_fell) # false

puts("Is the earth flat?")
puts(flat_earth_thesis) # true
```

Strangely, if I just run the statement itself, it returns false correctly `puts(horizon_flat and one_up_and_down and magellan_fell) # false`

But if I store that statement in a variable, and later call it, the variable outputs true. Why does Ruby think the earth is flat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you expect this:

```
flat_earth_thesis = horizon_flat and one_up_and_down and magellan_fell
```

To be evaluated as:

```
flat_earth_thesis = (horizon_flat and one_up_and_down and magellan_fell)
```

It is instead evaluated as:

```
(flat_earth_thesis = horizon_flat) and one_up_and_down and magellan_fell
```

As noted in comments, review [operator precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html).

Comment: This is why it's common to conform on `&&` instead of `and` in Ruby style guides. Since `&&` has higher precedence than `=`, `a = b && c && d` works as you would expect.

Comment: Interesting. So flat_earth_thesis was literally just assigned to horizon_flat, which is true. The other boolean values sit outside that evaluation, and cause the line to return false, rather than being assigned to the value.

Comment: I should read more style guides, because this fouled up a program I wrote, and it took me hours to figure out what the hell the problem was.

Comment: Yes. If you used the value of the entire expression `flat_earth_thesis = horizon_flat and one_up_and_down and magellan_fell` you would get `false`. As it is, this value is discarded.

Comment: @Chris check out [Using “and” and “or” in Ruby](https://avdi.codes/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) and the follow-up post [Ruby: On The Perl Origins Of “&&” And “||” Versus “and” And “or”](https://www.prestonlee.com/2010/08/04/ruby-on-the-perl-origins-of-and-versus-and-and-or/)